# Writing Dask partitions into single file

Tags: python, dask

New to `dask`,I have a `1GB` CSV file when I read it in `dask` dataframe it creates around 50 partitions after my changes in the file when I write, it creates as many files as partitions.
**Is there a way to write all partitions to single CSV file and is there a way access partitions?**
Thank you.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

#### Short answer

No, Dask.dataframe.to_csv only writes CSV files to different files, one file per partition.  However, there are ways around this.

#### Concatenate Afterwards

Perhaps just concatenate the files after dask.dataframe writes them?  This is likely to be near-optimal in terms of performance.

```
df.to_csv('/path/to/myfiles.*.csv')
from glob import glob
filenames = glob('/path/to/myfiles.*.csv')
with open('outfile.csv', 'w') as out:
    for fn in filenames:
        with open(fn) as f:
            out.write(f.read())  # maybe add endline here as well?
```

#### Or use Dask.delayed

However, you can do this yourself using [dask.delayed](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/delayed.html), by [using dask.delayed alongside dataframes](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/delayed-collections.html)

This gives you a list of delayed values that you can use however you like:

```
list_of_delayed_values = df.to_delayed()
```

It's then up to you to structure a computation to write these partitions sequentially to a single file.  This isn't hard to do, but can cause a bit of backup on the scheduler.

**Edit 1: (On October 23, 2019)**

In Dask 2.6.x, there is a parameter as `single_file`. By default, It is `False`. You can set it `True` to get single file output without using `df.compute()`.

For Example:

```
df.to_csv('/path/to/myfiles.csv', single_file = True)
```

Reference: [Documentation for to_csv](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.to_csv)

Comment: Thank you for your reply is there going to be any option in future releases where we can do it directly.

Comment: Another quick question if I do compute after everything it converts to pandas datafrme, so does it load the data in memory?

Comment: If you call `.compute()` on the dask.dataframe then you'll get a single pandas dataframe.  If you use dask.delayed then everything will be lazy.

Answer (score 5):

you can convert your dask dataframe to a pandas dataframe with the `compute` function and then use the `to_csv`. something like this:

> df_dask.compute().to_csv('csv_path_file.csv')

Comment: I like simple, intuitive, practical and clean code. :-)

Comment: But in this case you can just use pandas as df has to fit in memory.