# write dask dataframe to one file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dask

I can write a massive dask data frame to disk like so:

```
raw_data.to_csv(r'C:\Bla\SubFolder\*.csv')
```

This produces chunked data of the original (massaged) dataset in the subfolder:

```
C:\Bla\SubFolder\
```

Just wondering, can I force dask to write the data as one file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing Dask partitions into single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39566809/writing-dask-partitions-into-single-file)

Comment: @MRocklin thanks but is this really a solution? write everything in chunks and then put it all together again?

Answer (score 1):

To save everything into a single file one needs to pass [`single_file=True`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.to_csv) as

```
df.to_csv(r'C:\Bla\SubFolder\*.csv', single_file = True)
```