# How to read a large parquet file as multiple dataframes?

Tags: python, pyspark, dask, parquet, pyarrow

I am trying to convert a large parquet file into CSV.Since my RAM is only 8 GB, i get memory error.So is there any way to read parquet into multiple dataframes over a loop?

Comment: Surely if one partitions appropriately this can work? As stuff spills to disk...

Comment: Sorry,I couldnt understand your comment.Can you explain this ?@thebluephantom

Comment: This can be done using pyarrow library. You can read the data in batches, read certain row groups, or read certain columns only. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74163397/6563567

Answer (score 1):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
# initialise sparkContext
spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local').appName('myAppName') \
.config('spark.executor.memory', '4gb').config("spark.cores.max", "6").getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext

# Use SQLContext to read parquet file
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

# Read parquet file
df = sqlContext.read.parquet('ParquetFile.parquet')
```

> I have increased the memory and cores Here. Please try the same and
>   later you can convert to into csv.

Comment: Getting this error: py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o56.parquet.
: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with `dask` (https://dask.org/), which can work with larger than memory data on your local machine.
Example code to read a parquet file and save again as CSV:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = dd.read_parquet('path/to/file.parquet')
df.to_csv('path/to/new_files-*.csv')
```

This will create a collection of CSV files (https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.to_csv).
If you need a single CSV file, see this answer to do that: [Writing Dask partitions into single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39566809/writing-dask-partitions-into-single-file) (eg by concatenating them afterwards).